# Java JFileChooser endless loop

Tags: java, loops, libgdx, infinite-loop, jfilechooser

When i am closing my `JFileChooser` dialog, it opens again. I'm using the libgdx update for checking the input.

Here is the input code...

```
if(!SaveDialog.open) {
    if(input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S)) {
        SaveDialog.Save(pixmap);
    }
}
```

If I am pressing `S` very quickly, the dialog opens only one time, but if I am pressing it for like 2 sec, there will be a endless (I think) number of `JFileChooser` dialogs.

This is my code...

```
public class SaveDialog {
    private static boolean inited = false;
    private static JFileChooser fc;
    public static boolean open = false;

    public static void Init() {
        fc = new JFileChooser();

        fc.setFileFilter(new FileFilter() {
            public String getDescription() {
                return ".png";
            }
            public boolean accept(File f) {
                return f.getName().endsWith(".png");
            }
        });

        inited = true;
    }

    public static void Save(Pixmap pixmap) {
        open = true;

        if(!inited) {
            Init();
        }

        fc.showSaveDialog(null);

        byte[] data;
        try {
            data = PNG.toPNG(pixmap);
            FileHandle fh = new FileHandle(fc.getSelectedFile() + ".png");
            fh.writeBytes(data, false);
            open = false;
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            open = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone please help me with this problem.

Comment: What is the context of `if(!SaveDialog.open)`? If it is in an endless loop, your holding down s may be the problem. Try putting `System.out.println("Key pressed");` right under your `if(input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S))`. If it shows up repeatedly in console, that is your problem.

Comment: 1) It would help to see when the save dialog is called. 2) Instead of a static `JFileChooser`, consider creating a single instance of `SaveDialog` or even `JFileChooser`. 3) Instead of doing `if(!inited)`, consider using [Static Initialization Block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't help that isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S) determines if the S key is *currently* held down.

If you haven't given libgdx a chance to poll the input again before isKeyPressed() is called for the second time then I suspect that it will still think that it is held down.

If that isn't the issue, try recording the key's state and only open the dialog when it changes state from not pressed to pressed.

For example:

```
if(!SaveDialog.open) {
    boolean isSPressed = input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S);
    if(!wasSpressed && isSPressed) {
        SaveDialog.Save(pixmap);
    }
    wasSPressed = isSPressed;
}
```